# Drag & drop into Safari 5 results in unexpected file names

Tags: javascript, safari, drag-and-drop

I'm getting strange file names when I drop files into Safari.  Sometimes it works, sometimes the weird names appear.  I'm using `evt.dataTransfer.files` to read the dropped files.

How can this be mitigated?

[image: Screen of Safari and the files I dropped in]

[image: Debug screenshot at line 14]

[image: random files names]

Comment: more details please: Are the bogus characters always the same for a particular file? If you copy a file to a different directory, does that change the result? If you rename one of the files with bogus characters, do the characters still appear? Are the files with bogus characters consistent in some way? Does this problem happen ONLY in Safari?

Comment: the filenames are completely random. sometimes they even go through as they should. Moved them to another folder and still getting dodgy names.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that if i close safari and then reopen it; every time, it will send the correct names.

Comment: Sorry, didnt answer all your questions. Yes only in Safari, in Chrome and FF, they are ok. renaming the file didnt work.

Comment: I just tried a copy instead of moving the files to no avail

Comment: ok. now the one file i renamed, is not going in correctly with a fresh start of safari...

Comment: wow - now i just tried to drop a picture again and got be.grincheux.validator-rqzy68h5rh

Comment: just tried to break it in FF and Chrome to no avail :) Works as expected.

Comment: tried resetting safari including emptying the cache. no luck :(

Comment: What about e.dataTransfer.getData('public.file-url')? You could remove all non ascii characters to at least reduce the number of errors.

Comment: how would i get the public.file-url if its from a drop?

Comment: Im facing the same exact problem:
when I dragAndDrop a file on Safari
I got 2 times on 3 a weird filename and filesize=0 Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, i just assumed it was a bug and am awaiting an update

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who would like to try this... here is a full page.  Just open it in Safari and drop files in to the drop zone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #dropbox { border: 1px dashed #ccc; padding: 10px; margin: 10px 0; }
        #dropbox:hover { border: 1px dashed green; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function noop(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        function drop(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();

            var div = document.getElementById("files");
            var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                div.innerHTML += i + "=" + file.name + " " + file.size + " " + file.type + "<br/>";
            }
        }
        function addlistener() {
            document.getElementById("dropbox").addEventListener("dragenter", noop, false);
            document.getElementById("dropbox").addEventListener("dragover", noop, false);
            document.getElementById("dropbox").addEventListener("dragexit", noop, false);
            document.getElementById("dropbox").addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="addlistener()">
    <div id="dropbox">drop zone</div>
    <div id="files"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

these are the results i get

```
0=Chrysanthemum.jpg纽`d崰ၐ7 0 
1=Desert.jpgpg 0 
2=Hydrangeas.jpg 595284 image/jpeg
3=Jellyfish.jpg 0 
4=Koala.jpgȘ 0 
5=Lighthouse.jpg 561276 image/jpeg
6=Penguins.jpg 777835 image/jpeg
7=Tulips.jpg 620888 image/jpeg
```

Comment: i have a feeling its a safari bug with it reading in the bits after the filename and converting them to ascii

Comment: Do you remember what was the version for that Safari?

Comment: No I dont sorry but I keep my software up-to-date, so whatever was the version at the time of writing the original post.